# What is the difference between regex_token_iterator and regex_iterator?

Tags: c++, regex

Is there any difference between regex_token_iterator and regex_iterator?

It seems they both do same work but not sure which one is better performance?

Comment: If @ShafikYaghmour's answer solved your problem please accept it. I personally feel that it is a very good answer.

Answer (score 21):

There is indeed a difference between, if we look at cppreference it describes [std::regex_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator) as follows:

> std::regex_iterator is a read-only ForwardIterator that accesses the individual matches of a regular expression within the underlying character sequence.

and [std::regex_token_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator) as:

> std::regex_token_iterator is a read-only ForwardIterator that accesses the individual sub-matches of every match of a regular expression within the underlying character sequence. It can also be used to access the parts of the sequence that were not matched by the given regular expression (e.g. as a tokenizer).

So `std::regex_token_iterator` allows you to also match the non-matched tokens or the `n-th` sub-expression.

The cppreference section for `std::regex_token_iterator` that I linked above describes a typical implementation as follows:

> A typical implementation of std::regex_token_iterator holds the
>   underlying std::regex_iterator, a container (e.g. std::vector) of
>   the requested submatch indexes, the internal counter equal to the
>   index of the submatch, a pointer to std::sub_match, pointing at the
>   current submatch of the current match, and a std::match_results object
>   containing the last non-matched character sequence (used in tokenizer
>   mode).

The book [The C++ Standard Library](http://www.cppstdlib.com/) explains in `14.4` *Regex Token Iterators* as follows:

> A regex iterator helps to iterate over matched subsequences. However,
>   sometimes you also want to process all the contents between matched
>   expressions. [...] In addition, you can specify a list of integral
>   values, which represent elements of a “tokenization”:
>
> - -1 means that you are interested in all the subsequences between matched regular expressions (token separators).
> - 0 means that you are interested in all the matched regular expressions (token separators).
> - Any other value n means that you are interested in the matched nth subexpression inside the regular expressions.

The books site provides example code for [sregex_token_iterator](http://www.cppstdlib.com/code/regex/regextokeniter1.cpp.html) and [sregex_iterator](http://www.cppstdlib.com/code/regex/regexiter1.cpp.html) which should also be helpful.