# What is key difference between regex_iterator and regex_token_iterator?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, stl

Looking at the [regex_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator) and [regex_token_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator) I see that the key difference is the `value_type` which is:

- `match_results<BidirIt>` for the regex_iterator
- `sub_match<BidirIt>` for
  the regex_token_iterator

At the same time the examples for them (on these pages) show opposite behavior:

- `regex_iterator` splits by definition of the token itself in regex
- `regex_token_iterator` splits by delimiters description in regex

although, this in not specified in the aforementioned documents.

In the [What is the difference between regex_token_iterator and regex_iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320987/what-is-the-difference-between-regex-token-iterator-and-regex-iterator) it is specified that regex_token_iterator could have last parameter -1, 0, or 1 and I can’t find this at the [regex_token_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator). Is this is a kind of common knowledge that I miss or the document misses this?

My specific question is what makes them so different that the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string input_str = "hi, world";
    const std::regex  reg_ex(R"(\S+\w+|[,.])");

    std::vector<std::string> tokens { 
        std::sregex_token_iterator(input_str.begin(), input_str.end(), reg_ex, 0), 
        std::sregex_token_iterator() 
    };

    for (auto& item : tokens)
    {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
}
```

compiles and works without any issues and the same code based on the `sregex_iterator` doesn’t compile with many error messages which hide the information about the real issue. Actually, it can't make `vector<string>` from the iterators.

See the [demo with the issue](https://godbolt.org/z/x9eKEYfjr).

Is there any way to handle results of the regex_iterator in the same way as results of the `sregex_token_iterator` and pack them in `vector<string>` directly as in the example above?

Comment: Hmm, `std::sregex_token_iterator::operator*()` returns a reference to `std::sub_match<BidirIt>`, this is not `std::string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `std::sregex_token_iterator::operator*()` returns a reference to `std::sub_match<BidirIt>`, this is not `std::string`.
2. You construct a vector from an initializer list of two iterators. Invoking a correct constructor requires using parentheses.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string input_str = "hi, world";
    const std::regex  reg_ex(R"(\S+\w+|[,.])");

    std::vector tokens(
        std::sregex_iterator(input_str.begin(), input_str.end(), reg_ex), 
        std::sregex_iterator() 
    );

    for (const auto& item : tokens)
    {
        std::cout << item.str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Three extra questions here: (1) How switching to parentheses changes the game here? Why initializer list worked with sregex_token_iterator and doesn't work with the sregex_iterator? (2) Now this is a vector of smatches; it there a way to create a vector of strings on fly without extra conversion? Maybe some in-place converters, wrappers, etc.? (3) Any thoughts on the "last parameter -1, 0, or 1" in my initial question above; is this a documentation miss or mine?

Comment: (1) If there is an constructor that accepts `std::initializer_list<T>`, then it's used with `{...}` with all args of the same type. See [Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: (2) You can't do it this way - it requires an extra implicit conversion that is not performed. You might use `std::copy`, `std::transform`...

Comment: (3) This is [`submatch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator) parameter.